# for cicle exit in zsh

Tags: bash, for-loop, sh, zsh

I've recently changed my default shell from bash to zsh, I had a function in my bashrc for locate a file and executing the file. The function is fine with bash but with zsh my variable are empty and in particular the variable *$only_file*:

```
comp=$(locate -i -b -r "\.appimage$")

only_file=$(for x in $comp; do if [[ -f $x ]]; then echo $x; fi; done)
```

*$only_file* is empty.
I tried different "variants" (one-liner):

```
for x in "$comp"; [[ -e $x ]] && echo $x done;

for x in "$comp"; [[ -f $x ]] && echo $x

for x in $comp; do if [[ -f $x ]]; then echo $x; fi; done
```

all didn't print the result. So I tried only the for cycle:

```
for x in "$comp"; echo $x
```

and it's ok. I tried:

```
[[ -f "/path/to/file" ]] && echo "file" || echo "ERROR"
```

and echoed file; then:

```
[[ -f "/path/to/directory" ]] && echo "file" || echo "ERROR"
```

and echoed ERROR. So I thought something breaks the for cycle, I cleaned the list ($comp) and put only files (for a always true -f test), same result (void *$only_file*); I put a continue in the inner if:

```
for x in $comp; do if [[ -f $x ]]; then echo $x; continue; fi; done
```

same result. Now I'm out of idea, somebody can explain what I did wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that in zsh, your `for` loop will always be executed **exactly** once? So, unless the string stored in `$comp` happens to be the name of an existing file, `only_file` will be empty.

In bash, the content of `$comp` would undergo word splitting, and the loop body would be executed once for each word.

In `zsh` you could achieve the same effect by doing a

```
for x in ${(z)comp}
```